# What is "Unregister service workers" in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome

What is "Unregister service workers" in `Chrome dev tools ---> Application tab`? It is vague, and not self-explanatory at all.

If it's checked, it'll unregister all service workers? Or will "allow" them to be unregistered? Or will unregister a service worker as soon as a new one is available? Or maybe will unregister service workers on tab close?

I'm talking about this exactly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find more information in the article
[Service workers](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/browser/service_worker/README.md):

> Service workers are a web platform feature that form the basis of
> app-like capabilities such as offline support, push notifications, and
> background sync. A service worker is a event-driven JavaScript program
> that runs in a worker thread separate from a document.
>
> Once registered, a service worker is installed on the browser and
> persists indefinitely until evicted or deleted manually (see
> [Eviction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/content/browser/service_worker/README.md#Eviction)
> below). The browser dispatches events to the worker thread, starting
> the thread whenever needed and stopping it when there are no more
> events to dispatch.
>
> Service workers are bound to an origin. More specifically they have a
> scope URL, specified when the service worker is registered. The
> service worker controls pages or web workers that match its scope.
> There can be only one service worker registration for a given scope.

You can see all the Service workers installed on your computer by the URL
`chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, where you may individually
unregister them.

While debugging your own web-server, you may wish not to use the installed
Service workers, because they may be broken.
Dev Tools allows you in this case to:

- Unregister service workers : Unregisters all existing Service workers,
  but lets the website install new ones.
- Bypass for network : Avoid Service worker's register event from firing.

More references :

- [Service worker overview](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/service-worker-overview/)
- [Disable service workers when in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783790/disable-service-workers-when-in-development-mode)
- [No Service Worker extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-service-worker/mbhfklemgegigbfbfmfdmijkcnabgpmf)

Comment: Thank you, but aren't the two things it does a bit contradictory? **but lets the website install new ones** v.s. **Avoid Service worker's register event from firing**, as far as I know, for installing new service workers, the register event must fire to have the browser download its script first, and then comes the installation phase.

Comment: Also have I understood the answer correctly? So basically this is an option used while debugging/development for disabling all service workers temporarily?

Comment: (1) For the debugging of a website that installs service workers, you would want to uninstall the existing ones when testing a new version. (2) You would want to totally block them while testing a website that needs to remain functional without, for cases when the browser disallows installing service workers.